# Regex URL Rewrites

Tags: regex, redirect

I've been testing regexes for url rewrites and came across 2 that work, but I'm wondering which one is better.  Or if they're both bad, which would be the best way to handle the redirection requirement.

Essentially I'm looking to redirect any url that has a path with a common root.

Ex:

```
/pages/enteral-feeding-pump
/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/
/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/1234
/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/1234/
/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/1234/1234
/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/1234/1234/
```

etc.

These are 2 I have:

`^/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/?(?:[^\/]+\/?)*$`

`^/pages/enteral-feeding-pump/?(?:.*)`

I tested both, and they work, but I honestly don't know which is the best route to take.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but I would like to call out an issue with the regexes. The both will match `/pages/enteral-feeding-pump1234/24`. Since it doesn't have the same core path as the rest, I'm assuming this is not what you want. This regex should resolve that for you `^\/pages\/enteral-feeding-pump(?:$|\/(?:.+)?)`. [Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/kzLWnW/1)

Comment: I noticed the same issue and was trying to figure it out!  Thanks for the regex, a quick test shows it works.  If you set it as an answer to the question, I'll mark it as the accepted one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small issue with the regexs. Not sure how big of deal this is for you, but it's worth being aware of.

Both regexes will match the following url:

`/pages/enteral-feeding-pump1234/24`

Since it doesn't have the same core path, I'm assuming that you would not want to match against this. So below, I made a small correction to the Regexes you provided to prevent this from happening.

`^\/pages\/enteral-feeding-pump(?:$|\/(?:.+)?)`

The only thing I changed from the ones you provided is I'm requiring a `/` or end of line (`$`) directly after `enteral-feeding-pump`.

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/kzLWnW/1)